# Lambda calculus implementation using CBV small step operational semantics

Tags: functional-programming, f#, interpreter, semantics, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to implement an interpreter for the lambda calculus that has constant intergers and supports the addition operation. The interpreter should use the call-by-value small-step operational semantics. So I've implemented a `step` that should be able to reduce a lambda term by one step. However, the stepper is losing the surrounding program of the reduced subterm when reduced.

This is my implementation in F#:

```ml
type Exp =
  | Cst of int
  | Var of string
  | Abs of string * Exp
  | App of Exp * Exp
  | Arith of Oper * Exp * Exp
and Oper =
  Plus
```

and the stepper looks like this:

```ml
let rec step (exp : Exp) (env : Map<string, Exp>) : Exp =
  match exp with
  | Cst _ | Abs(_) -> exp
  | Var x ->
    match Map.tryFind x env with
      | Some v -> v
      | None -> failwith "Unbound variable"
  | App(e1, e2) ->
    match step e1 env with
      | Abs(x, e) ->
        let newEnv = Map.add x (step e2 env) env
        step e newEnv
      | e1' -> failwithf "%A is not a lambda abstraction" e1'
  | Arith(Plus, Cst a, Cst b) -> Cst (a + b)
  | Arith(Plus, e1, Cst b) -> Arith(Plus, step e1 env, Cst b)
  | Arith(Plus, Cst a, e2) -> Arith(Plus, Cst a, step e2 env)
  | Arith(Plus, a, b) -> Arith(Plus, step a env, step b env)
```

So, given the following example of a program `(\x.(\y.y x) 21 + 21) \x.x + 1`

```ml
App
  (Abs
     ("x", App (Abs ("y", App (Var "y", Var "x")), Arith (Plus, Cst 21, Cst 21))),
   Abs ("x", Arith (Plus, Var "x", Cst 1)))
```

I expect the `step` function to only reduce the `21 + 21` while keeping the rest of the program i.e. I expect the following output after one step `(\x.(\y.y x) 42) \x.x + 1`. However, I'm not able to retain the surrounding code around the `Cst 42`. How should I modify the program such that it reduction only steps once while maintaining the rest of the program?

Comment: You call step recursively and this is, why it is "multistep", yes? And the recursion ends when it hits something "terminal" i.e. non-recursive. If you really only want 1 operation at a time, I think the "standard" option is to rewrite this function in a non-recursive style first. This typically involves some form of manual stack with the "leftovers" after 1 step. `step env exp -> (env,exp)`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I believe the recursive call is necessary to resolve eventual bindings and environment updates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422032/rewriting-a-recursive-function-without-using-recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things that you should do differently if you want to implement standard small-step CBV lambda calculus.

- First, you want to always perform just one step. This means that you should always call `step` recursively only once. For example, you have `Arith(Plus, step a env, step b env)` - but this means that if you have an expression representing `(1+2)+(2+3)`, you will reduce this in "one step" to `3+5` but this is really two steps in one.
- Second, I don't think your way of handling variables will work. If you have `(\x.x+2) 1`, this should reduce to `1+2` using variable substitution. You could reduce this to `x+2` and remember the assignment `x=1` on the side, but then your function would need to work on expression alongside with variable assignment `Exp * Map<string, Exp> -> Exp * Map<string, Exp>`. It is easier to use normal substitution, at least for the start.

So, I would first define `subst x repl exp` which substitutes all free occurences of `x` in the expression `exp` with `repl`:

```
let rec subst (n : string) (repl : Exp) (exp : Exp) =
  match exp with 
  | Var x when x = n -> repl
  | Cst _ | Var _ -> exp
  | Abs(x, _) when x = n -> exp
  | Abs(x, b) -> Abs(x, subst n repl b)
  | App(e1, e2) -> App(subst n repl e1, subst n repl e2)
  | Arith(op, e1, e2) -> Arith(op, subst n repl e1, subst n repl e2)
```

Now you can implement your `step` function.

```
let rec step (exp : Exp) =
  match exp with
  // Values - do nothing & return
  | Cst _ | Abs _ -> exp 
  // There should be no variables, because we substituted them
  | Var x -> failwith "Unbound variable"

  // App #1 - e1 is function, e2 is a value, apply
  | App(Abs(x, e1), (Cst _ | Abs _)) -> subst x e2 e1
  // App #2 - e1 is not a value, reduce that first
  | App(e1, e2) -> App(step e1, e2)
  // App #3 - e1 is value, but e2 not, reduce that
  | App(Abs(x,e1), e2) -> App(Abs(x,e1), step e2)

  // Similar to App - if e1 or e2 is not value, reduce e1 then e2
  | Arith(Plus, Cst a, Cst b) -> Cst (a + b)
  | Arith(Plus, Cst a, e2) -> Arith(Plus, Cst a, step e2)
  | Arith(Plus, a, b) -> Arith(Plus, step a, b)
```

Using your example:

```
App
  (Abs
     ("x", App (Abs ("y", App (Var "y", Var "x")), Arith (Plus, Cst 21, Cst 21))),
   Abs ("x", Arith (Plus, Var "x", Cst 1)))
|> step
|> step
|> step
|> step
```

I get:

```
App (Cst 42, Abs ("x", Arith (Plus, Var "x", Cst 1)))
```

And if I'm correctly making sense of your example, this is correct - because now you are trying to treat a number as a function, which gets stuck.